# How to get element in table represented as Excel.ListObject in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How to get element in table represented as ListObject in C#?

It is very confusing.

```
Excel.ListObject table;
var temp = table.ListRows.Item[1].Range["A2"];
```

That code is not correct, I am just showing it here... Should I be doing something
similar?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Your table isn't connected to Excel in any way. If you would like to get an ListObject from Excel use something like:

```
Excel.ListObject table = activeWorksheet.ListObjects[1];
```

which will get you the first ListObject in the activeWorksheet.

If you want to create a list object from a Range do something like:

```
activeWorksheet.ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, activeWorksheet.Range["A1", "C10"]);
```

which will create a ListObject based on the supplied Range.

Comment: Wow...  I've been trying everything under the sun.  I assumed this was ListObjects[0], but it kept throwing a mysterious COM error.  Who knew the first element was [1].

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. Maybe you can accept it if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hopefully @user3111311 agrees.  All I can offer is my +1.  Thank you again...  I had wasted two hours debugging before I found this post.

Comment: How can I use the variable "table" to access read and eventually modify content of cells, i tried with table["ColumName"] but it not working ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the value of an element in an excel table (ListObject) in C#:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
Excel.ListObject tbl = ... // code to get the selected ListObject

// get element value by column name and row index
object val = ((Excel.Range)xtbl.Range.get_Item(RowInd, xtbl.ListColumns.get_Item(ColName).Index)).Value2;

// get element by row and column index
object val = ((Excel.Range)xtbl.Range.get_Item(RowInd, ColInd)).Value2;
```